# Find univariate distribution from multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a random variable, $X$, which is a vector of real numbers. It comes from a normal distribution: $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$. I know that the probability that the random variable $X$ is some given vector $x$ is $P(X=x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|2\pi \Sigma|}}\exp(-(x - \mu)^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}(x - \mu))$. However, I want to know the probability that just some component of $X$ is a given value. That is, **how do I find the probability, $P(X_i = x)$**?

EDIT: I should have wrote the pdf of $X$ and the pdf of $X_i$ at a given point, not the probability that $X$ or $X_i$ are equal to a given value.

Comment: $X_i$ is distributed as $X_i\sim \mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$. Certainly is $P(X_i=x)=0$ since $X_i$ is a continuous random variable.

Comment: @callculus So if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, then $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(u_i, \sigma_i^2)$? How do you know that's true?

Comment: Have a look at the first page of http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ig/MTH5118/Notes11-09.pdf

Comment: @callculus Ok, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach in the comments work with the density directly. Here is another approach that avoids the density altogether by using an alternate characterization of the Gaussian distribution.

---

The following is an important property of the multivariate Gaussian distribution.

> If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$, then $c_1 X_1 + \cdots + c_n X_n$ is Gaussian for any scalars $c_1,\ldots,c_n$.

In fact, this can be taken to be the [*definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) of the Gaussian distribution.

In particular, this implies $X_i$ is [univariate] Gaussian for any $i$. In order to specify the parameters of this Gaussian, we need to find its mean and variance, which can simply be read off from the mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$; that is, $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_{ii})$.

Comment: Follow-up here if you're interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281410/joint-distribution-of-subset-of-jointly-gaussian-random-variables.